# How can I run my HP Pavillion dv4000 laptop with VGA output only (using Win XP)?

Tags: vga, external-display, hp-pavilion, laptop-display

I'd like to use my old HP Pavillion dv4000 laptop as a media server by connecting it to a large monitor but I don't really want to have the laptop screen showing output.

The screen properties dialog doesn't let me disable the laptop screen and Fn-F5 doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Anybody know how to get this to work with this particular laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just me being ignorant.  Turns out I needed to press the fn-f4 key once more as it cycles through three options - laptop only - laptop + VGA - VGA only.  I was only pressing it once and expecting it to switch screens.